# How do i set equal characters in a line in a text view?

Tags: android, textview

So basically by default the text view in android wraps contents because of which my text looks something like this [image]

I'd like to disable the text wrapping property and set equal number of characters in the text view.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not 100% clear but if you're talking about justification, Android doesn't support it. But [here](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android) is a library which does.

If you literally don't want the text to wrap use:

```
android:singleline="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use single line "true", and define the padding between the cells.

ps: to set a number of characters , you have get the refference from this textView and edit the content(just format the string).
Example:

```
char text[] = originalText.toCharArray();
String newText = "":
    for(int i=0; i< text.length(); i++){
        if(i<x){
           newText =newText + text[i];
        }
        else{
           break;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, simply use the newline syntax "\n" where you want a new line to begin.

For example:

String text = "Who is the Boss? \n You are the Boss";

This can also be achieved programmatically of course in code if you're getting a string without one.

Simply write a method that checks for white space and insert the "\n" say after each successive 3 whitespaces have been detected. Then programmatically set the string to the TextView.

[image: The use of backslash and "n" to achieve multiple lines on TextView]

Answer (score -1):

try adding this attribute to your `textview` and then try

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal
```

Comment: Thank you my text looks much much better now:)